# how to remove the word archive from word-press titles

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, web-deployment

When I search the blog post on google its shows archives in the title how to remove them. I have found multiple links related to this problem but no one solves my problem. Please if any know helps me. Thank you in advance.

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by plugin
https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/

Or by using a filter:

> add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'my_theme_archive_title' );

More information: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_the_archive_title/